# Spring xml, array of arrays, or list of lists

Tags: arrays, xml, spring, list

How does one define an array of arrays in Spring xml?  Or a list of lists?  Tried many things (util:list, value-type="java.util.ArrayList", etc, etc etc, none worked.  Essentially:

```
<bean id="id">
   <array>
      <array>
         <value>aa</value>
         <value>ab</value>
         <value>ac</value>
      </array>
      <array>
         <value>ba</value>
         <value>bb</value>
         <value>bc</value>
      </array>
   </array>
</bean>
```

Or:

```
<bean id="id">
   <list>
      <list>
         <value>aa</value>
         <value>ab</value>
         <value>ac</value>
      </list>
      <list>
         <value>ba</value>
         <value>bb</value>
         <value>bc</value>
      </list>
   </list>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found something that worked.  Instead of trying to call the elements values, call them beans.  I little less than intuitive declaring a bean nested inside another bean, but it is allowed and works.

```
    <bean id="wxSetup" class="java.util.ArrayList">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean class="java.util.ArrayList">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <list>
                            <value>aa</value>
                            <value>ab</value>
                            <value>ac</value>
                        </list>
                    </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
                <bean class="java.util.ArrayList">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <list>
                            <value>ba</value>
                            <value>bb</value>
                            <value>bc</value>
                        </list>
                    </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```